# Debug Test for Apex in VS Code failing with error about wrong debug levels

Tags: apex, vs-code, apex-replay-debugger

I have created a very simple Apex class and a Test class to test it. When I run the test with 'Run Test' it executes as expected. When I run the test with 'Debug Test', VS Code shows an error dialog with 'The log must be generated with log categories Apex Code at the FINEST level and Visualforce at the FINER level'

When I look at the raw logs with the 'Run Test' the header is:

```
59.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,FINER;WAVE,DEBUG;WORKFLOW,INFO
```

The raw logs from 'Debug Test' the header is:

```
59.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
```

As you can see APEX_CODE has changed from FINEST to DEBUG and VISUALFORCE has changed from FINER to INFO.

I assume this must be happening with the CLI command that is changing the debug levels for the request. I can alternate 'Run Test' and 'Debug Test' and the log levels consistently show as above.

I ran the SFDX: Turn on Apex Debug Log for Replay Debugger and they all appeared to run successfully.

I can't find where I can see the commands that the extension uses to make the call to run 'Debug Test' to fix it.

I have also tried this on multiple dev orgs with the same result.

EDIT
So I just installed VS Code on another laptop and it works fine. So now I guess I have to find the VS code setting that is different between the two machines.

EDIT
I deleted vscode and manually deleted all of the extensions and I am still getting this error.

EDIT Reinstalled the OS and that fixed it.

EDIT The same issue has occurred. Can't keep reinstalling the OS